# how to fetch data after successful authentification with node, express and react (componentDidMount error)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication

I'm working on a Node-express-react project where I'm calling the Google Analytics reporting API to display some data on the client-side. Right now I have:

- my back-end and my front-end on two separate localhosts
- A Google Sign-in Button on the front-end redirecting to the back-end to run the OAuth 2.0 authentication process
- I'm calling the ga reporting API once I have the token.

Everything is working well so far. Now I'd like to pass the response from the API call to the client-side (react). I have the following `component`:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    // Pick whatever host/port your server is listening on
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/getData')
      .then(res => { // <-- The `results` response object from your backend
        // fetch handles errors a little unusually
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw res;
        }
        // Convert serialized response into json
        return res.json()
      }).then(data => {
        // setState triggers re-render
        this.setState({loading: false, data});
      }).catch(err => {
        // Handle any errors
        console.error(err);
        this.setState({loading: false, error: true});
      });
  }
```

Here is my API call on the server-side

```
router.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
    var token = req.query.token;
request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=' + token,  function (error, response, body) {
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    }else{
      console.log(JSON.parse(body))
          let views = []
   JSON.parse(body).items.forEach(view => {
            views.push({
              name: view.webPropertyId + ' - ' + view.name + ' (' + view.websiteUrl + ')',
              id: view.id
            })
          })
      console.log(views)
      res.send(views);

    }
});

})
```

The issue is that the `componentDidMount()` is being called before I click the Google login button which is running into an error because data from the API are not available (since no authentication has been done yet).

Which logic I should follow to have my data being fetch only once the login has been successful?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not make a check before making the fetch call?

`
componentDidMount(){ 
    if (!this.props.authenticated){ return; } 
    ... 
}
`

Comment: In that case the fetch would never run, as the component only mounts once and it would be prevented. I'm a bit confused as to the setup you're describing.  Is this all occurring within the same component? Doesn't OAuth force you to redirect to a new page after authenticating?

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington thanks for your comment. This is a google OAuth. When users click on the sign-in button there is a redirection to the server-side and a callback. then like I said once I have the token I'm making my API call. I've update my question with the API call. I guess you are confusing with the setup because I'm not sure how I should setup this... that is why I'm asking this question

Comment: Not sure if it's the best way, but you could redirect with the access token as a query param and pull it directly out of the URL into your fetch call and then store in state or session storage.

Comment: What do you mean? This is maybe the answer I'm looking for... at least one answer.